# Is programmers the right site for clothing issues?

Tags: support, on-topic-definition, site-rec

I would like to know if programmers.se is the right site to ask about clothing for coders etc. or if there is a better site.

Comment: see [dress-code tag at TWP](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dress-code) to find out what kind questions are okay there and what aren't

Comment: Thanks, I think I will find there what I want to know :)

Comment: lol! see @gnat, programmers implies people. One day, at least the title image at least needs to change to specify **Software Development** or something. Also, programmers are to wear sandals and sunglasses at all times.